# How to upload to Dropbox Public folder and get public URL?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a situation, where I need to upload a file to my Dropbox Public Folder, and also once uploaded I need to store the uploaded file's public url ? I am using python, and any help on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use this to set up a Python SDK in your program

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#python

This will give you all of the file information:

```
folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
```

I beleive you are talking about these short links, just so you know, every small link from the public folder is generated only by special request and has an expiration date.

If you want a permanent link skip to step 2.

### STEP 1

This information was taken from: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

```
/shares
```

DESCRIPTION

Creates and returns a shareable link to files or folders.

Note: Links created by the /shares API call expire after thirty days.

URL STRUCTURE

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/<root>/<path>`

`root` The root relative to which path is specified. Valid values are sandbox and dropbox.

`path` The path to the file or folder you want a shareable link to.

VERSIONS

0, 1

METHOD

POST

PARAMETERS

locale Use to specify language settings for user error messages and other language

specific text. See the notes above for more information about supported locales.

RETURNS

A shareable link to the file or folder. The link can be used publicly and directs to a preview page of the file. Also returns the link's expiration date in Dropbox's usual date format.

Sample JSON return value for a file

```
{
    "url": "http://db.tt/APqhX1",
    "expires": "Wed, 17 Aug 2011 02:34:33 +0000"
}
```

If you did step 1 don't do step 2.

### STEP 2

```
/files (GET)
```

DESCRIPTION

Downloads a file. Note that this call goes to the api-content server.

URL STRUCTURE

```
https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/<root>/<path>
```

root The root relative to which path is specified. Valid values are sandbox and dropbox.
path The path to the file you want to retrieve.

VERSIONS

0, 1

METHOD

GET

PARAMETER

rev The revision of the file to retrieve. This defaults to the most recent revision.

RETURNS

The specified file's contents at the requested revision.

The HTTP response contains the content metadata in JSON format within an x-dropbox-metadata header.

ERRORS

404 The file wasn't found at the specified path, or wasn't found at the specified rev.

NOTES

This method also supports HTTP Range Retrieval Requests to allow retrieving partial file contents.`

DONE